# Rich Text field is producing weird space character instead of &nbsp;

Tags: richtext, whitespace

1. Example from the frontend

   [image: Example from the frontend]
2. Example in dev tools

[image: Example in dev tools]

3. If I "view-source" on the page

[image: If I "view-source" on the page]

4. Example from Rich Text Field

[image: Example from Rich Text Field]

5. Example from Rich Text Field HTML

[image: Example from Rich Text Field HTML]

This is a Rich Text field within a matrix, it's output in the template like this: `{{ block.text }}`

If I pass the "|raw" filter I get the same.

If you notice, the Rich Text Field has a   before the closing `</p>`, which isn't output in the markup, instead I get this strange character.

I had a similar thing with hacksaw recently bringing up this character here:
https://github.com/ehousestudio/craft_hacksaw/issues/16

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Could you copy and paste the strange character into the bottom field on this page and update your post with the results: http://www.freeformatter.com/string-utilities.html

Comment: This happens to me in my mamp environment as well. But not on my live server. I guess it's more of an server encoding problem (UTF8 vs. something else).

Comment: @StephenHamilton here is the character's results on that page: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ipbhqt75dxo0vvy/Screenshot%202016-10-05%2016.40.57.png?dl=0

Further info on it: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0fffd/index.htm

Comment: @KSPR this site is only local (on mamp) right now, DB is on utf8 general ci

Comment: @joe Sounds like an environment issue then, could you maybe give us some more info on your web server setup?

Comment: @StephenHamilton you may have read my last answer to KSPR before I edited it, I incorrectly said it was on 2 servers (it is not). There is only 1 environment, running on MAMP, php 5.6.10 & apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did contact Craft about this near the time this question was posted, they were not sure why it was occuring.

I found that this issue was environment specific, it was specifically happening locally on MAMP4, with 5.6.* using NGINX.

I was unable to find the cause of the issue, but, in the end it was not happening on server environments so I decided to give up.